# Importing pandas using reticulate

Tags: python, r, conda, reticulate

I seem to be getting the error message:

```
attempt to apply non-function
```

on my shiny app when trying to run a prediction using a model saved as a pickle. From what I am seeing, the problem emanates from trying to import pandas using the reticulate package.

When I try and run this line of code:

```
p <- import("pandas")
```

I get this error message

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Users\User\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 196, in <module>
    if pandas.compat.PY37:
```

Not sure what to do